# Using EPPlus to create excel sheets based on an xltm template?

Tags: excel, templates, epplus

I'm using EPPlus to create spreadsheets for download from a website.

This is all working.

What would be nice though is if I could create the spreadsheets based on an xltm template file.
Is this possible?